# Form factor and average value

Tags: electricity, voltage

Why Our Electricity Flowing in the Sequence of 11kv,33,66,132kv,why not Flow in 10 kv,11,12,13,14 that Sequence.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? It's a little unclear what you're talking about.

Comment: I'd guess the OP is asking why choose 11kV, 33kV and 66kV for the various stages in power transmission? What is special about these numbers? I don't think there is anything special about those numbers and I suspect they're an accident of history.

Answer (score 2):

11kv,33,66,132kv may be standard in the UK and India, but this is not universal. This is not the stardard in the USA.

11kv,33,66,132kv are step downs by interger factors from 400 kV, by factors of 2 or 3 at each step, perhaps to have interger ratios of transformer windings.

Comment: I did wonder about the obvious integer ratios, but then I can't see any technical reason why a transformer ratio needs to be an integer.

Comment: @JohnRennie I don't see any good reason either, although this source claims there is one http://www.linkedin.com/groups/Why-substations-are-always-in-2121109.S.150344606